# How can I get or play sounds from a tablet DAW?

Tags: learning, daw

I invested in a tablet and downloaded a couple of apps just to get a feel for all this, and I know I'm going to sound like an idiot, but after downloading Touch DAW and other similar apps, how do I go about getting sounds onto there? Do I need to buy some physical tools or can I get sample packs offline? This is really confusing but I'm going to keep researching and asking questions until I figure it out.

Comment: You should list the other apps you're using. As far as TouchDAW [do you mean this](http://www.humatic.de/htools/touchdaw/)? Because as far as I can tell that won't help you. It's an app to *control* a DAW—for instance one running on your laptop/desktop—but not a DAW itself. As far as the rest of your question it depends greatly on the rest of your setup. Some apps have sounds built in or are synths themselves. Others can import sounds or use other apps. Also try to give your questions a more specific title. For instance "How to get or play sounds from tablet DAW?" might be more helpful.

Comment: That actualy makes sense but can i use an actual daw from my tablet or am i going to need a laptop or computer ?

Comment: Sure, there are all kinds of music apps for tablets. Somebody else will have to help with you with the specifics. I'm an iOS user so I wouldn't be much help with Android apps. But there are plenty of apps for both platforms and some people use *only* tablets/phones. If it *was* me answering the question I'd want more details like what other apps you have and what you want to achieve? Like do you want to record voice or acoustic/external instruments? Because that *would* require some hardware, but getting started with sample-based music wouldn't.

Comment: Can you play an instrument? If so, recording that is a good place to start. If not, finding an app that includes sounds that you don't have to record yourself is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to wrap some of what @user37496 and @ToddWilcox mentioned in comments into an answer, just to ensure we keep it.

Firstly Touch DAW is a controller for a Digital Audio Workstation (DAW) so it doesn't do anything to do with audio itself. It needs a DAW.

Once you have a DAW you need some audio, whether that be wav or midi with samples or any other audio file type your DAW can cope with.

- You can get midi samples for all instruments easily online. Free ones are available, but often the collections you pay for are better (higher resolution, more accurate sound etc)
- If you have an electric instrument you can play into your DAW and let it record your music
- A microphone allows you to sing or record acoustic instruments into it

You may also, depending on the hardware and applications you are running, and what you want to do, require an external mixer or audio interface.

Comment: also, search this stack for "VST ASIO DAW" you'll find a lot of Q&A with tips and pitfalls

Answer (score 0):

Walkband and Soundcamp are two that have virtual instruments you can play using the touchscreen.I use Chordbot to play around with chord progressions. You set up the parameters of the progression and it plays it in a loop. If you want a full recording type of software- like a DAW- you can get a much more sophisticated one for a PC than a tablet. All the DAWs I have seen for tablets are pretty simplistic. However, if you are just exploring PC based music, simple may be better.